# runST within Reader

Tags: haskell

I would like to make some of my code more "monadic" and to use a Reader monad rather than passing around a common environment. But somewhere I have to use mutable vectors, and hence the ST monad as well; to make things interesting, the ST action needs to access the environment (but the rest of the function does not). In other words, this works:

```
aux :: Int -> Reader Env Double
aux i = -- something

bla :: [a] -> Reader Env Double
bla l = do e <- ask
           return $ runST $ do -- something producing an Int
                               let o = runReader (aux i) e
                               -- something else depending on o
                               return something
```

but it feels very ugly and wrong, kind of a convoluted way to still pass the environment explicitly; I would like `bla` to look more like this:

```
bla :: [a] -> Reader Env Double
bla l = return $ runST $ do -- something producing an Int
                            o <- ??? aux i
                            -- something depending on o
                            return something
```

Does it make sense? Is it possible? If yes, what do I have to put instead of `???` ? I guess the true question would be, what is a good way to achieve this kind of thing? What design would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix `Reader` with `ST` using `ReaderT`. Something like that:

```
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Reader

type Env = String

type ReaderST s = ReaderT Env (ST s)

foo :: ReaderST s [Int]
foo = do
  str <- ask
  let len = length str
  a <- lift (newArray (0, len - 1) 0 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int))
  a' <- lift $ mapArray (+ 2) a
  es <- lift $ getElems a'
  return es

run :: [Int]
run = runST $ runReaderT foo "xyz"

-- > run
-- [2,2,2]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of `lift`s all over the place, which are a bit difficult to figure out, but it does look much better ... (and for some reason it runs about 100 times faster as well - the runST is a big loop)

Comment: @Vincent `ReaderT r m a` is a data type which holds a function `r -> m a` (`Env -> ST s a` in this case). And `lift` just turn any `value :: m a` (e.g. `ST s a` which returned by `newArray`, `mapArray`, `getElems`, etc.) into such function (using `const value`) and wrap it with `ReaderT` constructor. Looking at [the code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html) can help.

Comment: And `Reader r` is just `ReaderT r Identity` btw.

Comment: @VincentBeffara You only need one lift. Moving the individually lifted expressions to a single lifted expression is easy (a new `do` block) and may have slightly better performance depending on the `Monad` (probably no difference with `ReaderT`). Look at https://gist.github.com/3024433

Comment: Sure, but IIUC the call to 'ask' has to live outside of this block, as well as all <- arrows. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the `ReaderT` monad transformer and stack it on top of `ST`? Like here: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html

Comment: Aha! I hadn't thought of that. In my mind the whole runST thing is like a temporary variable, and I did not want it to somehow 'leak out' from bla (initially it was doing it without mutable vectors).I will try and see if I can do it your way